# Having a string as a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 20K objects and a set of features provided in a list. I need to extract those features from each object and save them into a dictionary. Each object has almost 100 features.

For example:

```
# object1
Object1.Age = '20'
Object1.Gender = 'Female'
Object1.DOB = '03/05/1997'
Object1.Weight = '130lb'
Object1.Height = '5.5'

#object2
Object1.Age = '22'
Object1.Gender = 'Male'
Object1.DOB = '03/05/1995'
Object1.Weight = '145lb'
Object1.Height = '5.8'

#object3
....
```

And the list of features that I need to extract from each object:

```
features = ['Gender', 
            'DOB', 
            'Height']
```

I'm trying to prepare a dictionary for each object with the specified features such that:

```
dict1 = {features[0]:Object1.features[0], features[1]:Object1.features[1], features[2]:Object1.features[2]}

dict2 = {features[0]:Object2.features[0], features[1]:Object2.features[1], features[2]:Object2.features[2]}

dict3 = ...
```

Since the list of features may be change in future, I need the code to be flexible. I'm sure this is not the way that I can prepare the dictionary for each object but I wrote this to show the problem.

How can I write the dictionaries?

Comment: How are your objects actually defined? Are they in some kind of container or do you just have 20k separate variables?

Comment: @excazaThey are 20k different DICOM objects, separated from each other.

Comment: So... you have 20k separate variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension wrapping a `getattr` call:

```
def get_features(obj, features):
    return {f: getattr(obj, f) for f in features}
```

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension

```
objdict = {feature: getattr(obj, feature) for feature in features}
```

You have to make sure the strings in features do match with the attribute name of the object.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of dictionaries:

```
features = ['Gender', 'DOB', 'Height']
your_objects = [Object1, Object2]  # ...
list(map(lambda el: {f: getattr(el, f) for f in features}, your_objects))
```

Since you have a lot of objects it may be handy to iterate over the map object without casting it to a `list`.